# How to drag the element and drop into the certain element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to do the `drag and drop` feature in my codes.

There are at least two `tables` in my page and I want to drag `table 1 cell` to `table 2 cell`.

most of `table 2` cells are empty.

My html

```
Table 1

<table class = 'dragtable'>

//bunch of cells...

</table>


Table 2

<table class = 'dragtable'>

//bunch of cells...

</table>
```

In my codes:

```
  obj = $('.dragtable td');
   emptyCell = $('.dragtable td:empty');
   $(obj).draggable({
       cursor:'pointer',
       snap:emptyCell
   })
```

My codes above can make the user drag the cell but I need to make sure the user can only drop the item to the empty cell not everywhere in the page. The `emptyCell` doesn't work in my case.

PS: I can't change the table `class` name because it affects many other things.

Any tips here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to make your empty cells droppable see the link below
http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: thanks but I only want to drop the item to the empty cell not everywhere in the page. +1

Comment: yes so you would make your empty cell(s) droppable ... $(yourEmptCell).droppable(options)

if you read the link i sent you above it clearly states "Create targets for draggable elements."